# Как получить номер строки активной ячейки таблицы SpreadsheetApp?

Tags: javascript, google-docs

Есть метод `SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getActiveCell()[1];`
Он возвращает undefined.... 
какие еще существуют методы для получения номера строки выделенной ячейки ?

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getActiveCell().getRow()` вернет номер строки активной ячейки. Подробнее - [тут](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow())

Comment: Проблема в том, что данный метод за активную считает первую ячейку и возвращает " 1 ".

Comment: А что он должен вернуть?